# What is the syntax for Row Based Time Calculations is SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, logic, case

I am fairly new to T-SQL. I am able to get my desired outcome using Excel but its time consuming (or impossible) for large data sets and its prone to errors. I need help to write a T-SQL Syntax for the following narration:

1. If the MSISDN column is arranged in ascending order,
2. for every identical MSISDN value, provided the value in the TransactionKey column equals “BUNDLE”,
3. let the CulcExpirationDate (that means create a new column called ‘CulcExpirationDate’),
4. for the earliest TransactionTime value, let the succeeding TransactionTime value in the TransactionTime column be the CulcExpirationDate value,
5. provided its less than the value in the corresponding NewExpirationDate column,
6. otherwise retain the NewExpirationDate column value.

For sample data table please follow the link: https://rextester.com/BLZVD95238

### [Below is the screenshot of the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6qME.png)

Comment: In order to do this in SQL, you would need to query the table(s) that hold the data.   In order to help you do this, we would need to know the details of your tables.

Comment: Hi @TabAlleman thank you for the feedback. I edited my question, I hope the table details are enough in order for you to assist me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's some confusing language in your post. You say "Repeat steps 4, 5 & 6 for every row with identical MSISDN value." which could mean that every row should have a CulcExpirationDate, but you've only populated one in your example.

You've also highlighted MSISDN values that you said were identical, but you included both 248 and 258.

I've tried to come up with a solution based on your information using a dummy table with a limited set of what you provided in your image. You can see that the entries with the earliest TransactionTime values for MSISDN 248 and 258 have been populated with a CulcExpirationDate value corresponding to the next TransactionTime value for the respective MSISDN. All other values are NULL.

Test here: https://rextester.com/IPQ11749

[image: Example results]

```
CREATE TABLE rowBasedTimeCalc
(
    MSISDN INT
    ,TransactionTime DATETIME
    ,TransactionKey CHAR(50)
    ,Reference CHAR(50)
    ,NewExpirationDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO dbo.rowBasedTimeCalc
VALUES
(248, CONVERT(DATETIME,'28/10/2018 02:45:43',103), 'Bundle', 'DATA1GB',convert(DATETIME,'07/11/2018 02:45:43',103)),
(248, convert(DATETIME,'08/10/2018 07:58:23',103), 'Bundle', 'DATA1GB',convert(DATETIME,'28/10/2018 06:58:23',103)),
(258, convert(DATETIME,'08/10/2018 12:39:28',103), 'Bundle', 'DATA1GB',convert(DATETIME,'18/10/2018 12:39:28',103)),
(258, convert(DATETIME,'13/10/2018 06:05:44',103), 'Bundle', 'DATA1GB',convert(DATETIME,'23/10/2018 06:05:44',103)),
(258, convert(DATETIME,'28/09/2018 17:35:00',103), 'Bundle', 'DATA1GB',convert(DATETIME,'08/10/2018 17:35:00',103)),
(258, convert(DATETIME,'19/10/2018 00:27:24',103), 'Bundle', 'DATA1GB',convert(DATETIME,'28/10/2018 23:27:24',103)),
(258, convert(DATETIME,'28/10/2018 11:35:16',103), 'Bundle', 'DATA1GB',convert(DATETIME,'07/11/2018 11:35:16',103)),
(258, convert(DATETIME,'11/10/2018 00:37:43',103), 'Bundle', 'DATA1GB',convert(DATETIME,'21/10/2018 00:37:43',103)),
(258, convert(DATETIME,'04/10/2018 23:46:28',103), 'Bundle', 'DATA1GB',convert(DATETIME,'14/10/2018 23:46:28',103)),
(258, convert(DATETIME,'25/10/2018 04:04:35',103), 'Bundle', 'DATA1GB',convert(DATETIME,'04/11/2018 03:04:35',103)),
(258, convert(DATETIME,'03/10/2018 01:19:39',103), 'Bundle', 'DATA1GB',convert(DATETIME,'13/10/2018 01:19:39',103)),
(258, convert(DATETIME,'25/09/2018 01:54:13',103), 'Bundle', 'DATA1GB',convert(DATETIME,'05/10/2018 01:54:13',103)),
(258, convert(DATETIME,'22/10/2018 22:09:29',103), 'Bundle', 'DATA1GB',convert(DATETIME,'01/11/2018 22:09:29',103));

WITH dateFinder AS
(
SELECT 
    *
    ,rowID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MSISDN ORDER BY TransactionTime)
    ,culc = lead(transactiontime) over (PARTITION BY MSISDN ORDER BY TransactionTime)
FROM dbo.rowBasedTimeCalc
WHERE TransactionKey = 'Bundle'
)

SELECT 
    dateFinder.MSISDN
    ,dateFinder.TransactionTime 
    ,dateFinder.TransactionKey
    ,dateFinder.Reference
    ,dateFinder.NewExpirationDate
    ,CulcExpirationDate = 
        CASE 
            WHEN dateFinder.rowID = 1 AND culc < dateFinder.NewExpirationDate THEN dateFinder.culc
            ELSE NULL
        END 
FROM dateFinder

DROP TABLE dbo.rowBasedTimeCalc
```

Comment: thank you very much for your assistance, it has been very helpful and its pointing me in the right direction.
On you advise, i edited my question to make my desired result clearer but fulling in all the rows on me screenshot. I also added a table with sample data to assist you https://rextester.com/BLZVD95238

Your result managed to fill in only two rows correctly, however, in looking for a syntax that helps me fill in all the rows in the CulcExpirationDate column as shown in the desired result screenshot. 
Your continued assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Dingyrton Is CulcExpirationDate in row 18 of your image what you expect it to be? The succeeding transaction time is row 19 - 09/10/2018 14:41:07, but that is greater than the corresponding NewExpirationDate from row 18. By my understanding, the CulcExpirationDate for row 18 should default to its NewExpirationDate of 08.10.2018 01:00:00. I've made a small change to the CASE statement to populate CulcExpirationDate for every row. Please try this and see if it works for you: https://rextester.com/TPUT13326

Comment: thank you very much for answering the question !! You are truly amazing !!! Your code works wonders !!! You are truly awesome. The syntax even runs on my data check here https://rextester.com/edit/BLZVD95238 .